# how to prove a theorem about linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I don't know how to prove that

$\phi$ is a linear operator of derivating, $\psi$ -multiplying on $x$ in infinite space of all polynomials with real coefficients. Prove that $\phi\psi^n-\psi^n\phi=n\psi^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the product rule $(fg)'=f'g+g'f$$$\phi(\psi^n(f))-\psi^n(\phi(f))=\phi(x^nf)-x^nf'=nx^{n-1}f+x^nf'-x^nf'=nx^{n-1}f=n\psi^{n-1}(f)$$